# My implementation of the factory method is correct?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I am study factory method pattern and after reader in some places i did the following implementation. If in the future there is a need to add new types of boards, every time I have to change the BoardFactory class and the enum? Is this the correct approach to implement factory method?

```
public interface Board { }

public class MotherBoard implements Board { }

public class VideoBoard implements Board { }

public class AudioBoard implements Board { }

public enum BoardType {
    VIDEO,
    AUDIO,
    MOTHER_BOARD
}

public class BoardFactory {

    private BoardFactory() { }

    public static Board createBoard(BoardType boardType) {
        switch (boardType) {            
            case VIDEO:
                return new VideoBoard();
            case AUDIO:
                return new AudioBoard();
            default:
                return new MotherBoard();
        }
    }   
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board b1 = BoardFactory.createBoard(BoardType.VIDEO);
        Board b2 = BoardFactory.createBoard(BoardType.AUDIO);
        Board b3 = BoardFactory.createBoard(BoardType.MOTHER_BOARD);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a factory pattern, but this seems more like Simple Factory rather than Factory Method, since the pattern used doesn't let you specify the factory type (should there be different types of `BoardFactory`).

If you would like to use the Factory Method then you should

1) Define a common interface or abstract class that serves as "Creator"
2) Instantiate an instance of a Creator and remove the static modifier from `createBoard`

something along the lines of

```
abstract class AbstractFactory {
 public abstract BoardType createBoard(BoardType boardType);
}  

class BoardFactory extends AbstractFactory {
 // Implementation
}

class AwesomeBoardFactory extends AbstractFactory {
 // Implementation
}

public static void main(String[] args){
 AbstractFactory factory = new AwesomeFactory();
 Board b1 = factory.CreateBoard(BoardType.MOTHER_BOARD);
}
```

[Reading material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058623/when-is-factory-method-better-than-simple-factory-and-vice-versa) on the [difference](http://corey.quickshiftconsulting.com/1/post/2009/5/first-post.html).

Comment: @Andrey: [This is also a great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4211307/69809) which describes all the different factory types along with UML diagrams.